# Convert "H264 MP4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)"/"MPEG AAC 48kHz" 1080p 23.976000fps videos to 720p, as complete quality as possible

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, avconv, hd-video

`file` says all the files are `ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2` and the title's info is from VLC 2.0.9. IMO 1080p isn't necessary, especially since the other vids from earlier are 720p and are just fine; I don't know and aren't sure but I think all these vids are HD, which explains their size. The rest of the info given by VLC during playback, for completeness:

```
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
```

I've found not just one answer and they all use `ffmpeg` but `avconv` is the successor; I know, they're same thing, for most part at least. I know from experience `avconv` doesn't accept some options designed for `ffmpeg`. Not to mention that both have options which sound similar within same program but have totally different results.

Comment: `ffmpeg` and `avconv` are not the same thing. See [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Get `ffmpeg`

It is always a good idea to use a recent build when encoding with `ffmpeg`. Development is very active and using a recent build will allow you to avoid fixed bugs while giving you access to the latest features.

There are two main methods to get `ffmpeg` and neither will interfere with packages from the repository including the so-called "ffmpeg" package:

### Using a static build

This is simply a binary that someone else compiled. All you do is download, extract, and run it (note the `./` before `ffmpeg`):

```
wget http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/32bit/ffmpeg.static.32bit.$(date +"%F").tar.gz
tar xzvf ffmpeg.static.32bit.$(date +"%F").tar.gz
./ffmpeg -i input.mp4 <your options> output.mkv
```

### Compiling `ffmpeg`

When compiling you control exactly how `ffmpeg` is configured and also allows you to use certain encoders, such as `libfdk_aac`, that are not available in the static builds.

Just follow a step-by-step guide: [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide). If you can copy and paste you can compile `ffmpeg`.

---

## 2. Encode

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -c:a copy out.mkv
```

In this example:

- The [`scale` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) to resize the video. With `scale` you can just declare one dimension, height in this case, and use `-1` in the other. `ffmpeg` will then automatically calculate the correct value while maintaining the aspect ratio.
- The encoder `libx264` will produce H.264 video. Quality is controlled with `-crf`. The range is a log scale of 0 to 51. 0 is lossless (files will likely be huge), 18 is often considered to be "visually lossless", 23 is default, and 51 is worst quality. Generally you use the highest value that still gives you an acceptable quality.
- Video *encoding speed/compression efficiency* for this encoder is controlled with the `-preset`. These are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow. Default is "medium". Generally you use the slowest preset that you have patience for.
- For a set of videos use the same `-crf` and `-preset` for all of them.
- The audio will be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) from the input to the output. Think of it like a copy and paste.
- The Matroska output container will be used. It supports more formats not it is not as widely supported by players and devices as MP4 for example.

### Encoding all videos

You can use a bash "for loop" to encode all videos in a directory:

```
mkdir encoded
for f in *.avi; do ./ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset fast -c:a copy encoded/"${f%.avi}.mkv"; done
```

---

## Also see

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)

Comment: A nice answer. The speed presets sound like the program will slack more instead of working, but that's not the case, instead slower=better result ?

Comment: @Rautamiekka A preset allows you to set the tradeoff for encoding efficiency vs encoding speed. A fast preset is less efficient, so it is faster. A slower preset has better compression (quality per file size). So a slower preset will give you better compression at a slower encoding speed.

Comment: [ERROR] `for f in *.mp4 do; ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:a copy encoded/"${f%.mp4}.mp4"; done` _<new line>_
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ffmpeg'`

Comment: I figured out that error: the semicolon should be before 'do'. However, there's another issue which is even easier: simply calling `ffmpeg` calls the installed version, so to call the separate version one needs `./` before the program name, so that's solved. I'll leave this laptop process the files over the night and will get back to you once I can watch them.

Comment: @Rautamiekka Sorry for the typo. Fixed.

Comment: I think I got just what I was looking for, so it's time to close this one as answered. Thanks for the effort, which works perfectly, although I changed few parameters to get the very best; as far as my quick viewing of the vids went, I can't even tell which was the original.

Comment: Wait just a minute ! The 720p vids are over 2.5 times larger than the original 1080p ones.

Comment: @Rautamiekka You need to show your ffmpeg command and the complete console output.

Comment: The comment showing the error shows the whole command. I can't show the console output since the output isn't saved anywhere and the laptop has been rebooted and shutted down couple of times.

Comment: LordNeckbeard, the far larger files issue still isn't fixed, in case you forgot about this.

Comment: @Rautamiekka What can I suggest without any additional information from you? Ideally an input sample, your command, and the complete ffmpeg console outputs would be needed to duplicate any issue.

Comment: I said the error I posted earlier shows the command I used. And I said that I don't have the outputs, unless they're saved to a file I didn't know about. If you really want outputs, all I can do is re-run the processing.

Comment: @Rautamiekka I can't give any suggestions without this information. Otherwise I can only guess.

Comment: `./ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset veryslow -c:a copy encoded/"${f%.mp4}.mp4"`.

Comment: @Rautamiekka `-crf 0` means lossless, and lossless creates huge files.

Comment: I thought it'd simply take the frames and resize them without changing the quality, but instead it disabled the compression on all frames. I want as identical quality as possible, so I'll re-run with `-crf 1`.

Comment: @Rautamiekka As mentioned in the answer you should use the highest crf value that still gives you an acceptable quality. Start with 23 and go up or down. You don't have to encode the whole thing to get an idea of the output (see `-t` and `-ss`  options).

Comment: Which implies you're saying to take short clips and check them. Smart idea, I'll see about that.

Comment: Ok, it seems `20`-`21` are so much like the original that I couldn't tell difference, but I made it `19` to be sure. Also using `placebo` instead of `veryslow`. `placebo` makes it really slow regardless of `19`, but the processing is 3-4 times faster than with `1`, so I'm happy enough with that. My Dell laptop just doesn't have the fastest Dual Core out there, but the 6 or 7 instruction sets FFmpeg is using makes it a whole lot faster, unlike my dad's Acer laptop which has 3 slow sets in use, making it half slower to process, although it's otherwise faster CPU.

Comment: @Rautamiekka placebo is a waste of time (hence the name). It helps at most ~1%. That is why I did not list it in the answer.

Comment: I know, but 1% is alot in a large project.

Comment: The first is in: originally 950.6MB, became 292.2MB. That's 3.25 times larger originally, rounded. Quality is so close to the original I don't think `-crf` needs to be any higher or lower from `19` with `placebo`.

Comment: @Rautamiekka You can choose the answer as "accepted" if you found it acceptable so others know it has been answered.

Comment: If I had the CPU available I'd test out the other presets, but I have to hope ppl will read all the comments before using your command readily. The command certainly doesn't go by the requirement to have the result as completely near the original as possible, but it seems there's so much variation the files will be very large even if nothing else was done, that it's either complete quality & very large file or lesser quality & reasonably large file.

Comment: @Rautamiekka Also, quality is subjective so no "one answer" is perfect.

Comment: You're right, but I believe in this case it's easy: take the original work and do nothing else but resize down to 720p.

Comment: @Rautamiekka Filtering requires re-encoding, and usage of a lossy encoder will introduce quality loss (even if you do not notice it). Using a lossless encoder will, in most cases, result in a huge file.